# TFS build service with Git failing

Tags: git, build-process, tfs-2015

TFS 2015 with VS 2015
Source control: TFS Git project
Process template: default git process template

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve the problem we have. The xaml build are failing everytime. It does not seems to be able to retrieve the code from the git project.

I have the exact same server / pc config in a LAB (clone from production on a subnetwork). In the lab, it’s working.

```
Error:
Exception Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found). (type LibGit2SharpException)Exception Data Dictionary:libgit2.code = -1libgit2.category = 12
Exception Stack Trace: Server stack trace: 
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)
at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitClone.GetRepository(String repositoryUrl, String workingFolder, Boolean checkoutSubmodules)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
at System.Func`4.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitRepositoryBase.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

Comment: The error looks like a 404, I'd double check the repo paths in the build definition.

Answer (score 0):

Check you are using Repository URL in Source Settings, and access it manually to see whether you can open this URL:

[image]

Comment: Tried that. The path works but same error when running the build. We just did the upgrade from tfs2010 to 2015. Is this a missing configuration? if so, where?

Comment: If you create a new GIT team project and queue build, will you reproduce this issue?

Comment: I have errors for all the project i'm trying to build. Even a new one just created using the vs template without adding anything to it.

Comment: Is TFVC build working? How do you specify the Projects path in the build definition? Please try to create a new build agent to see whether you'll reproduce this issue.

Comment: I have 2 tfs collection.The build are already working on the old collection with tfs as source control. I'm now using Git inside tfs. I only have one build service. I need to reconfigure the build service to change collection. I don't have problem with that part and the agent and controller are running. I just tried to create a new git project in my old collection and make a build definition for it. The build still has the same error. It's not able to retrieve the code to build it. From the previous screenshot "source settings", I also tried to check or uncheck the box without any good results